# Most basic PowerBI python script

Tags: python, pandas, powerbi

I am looking to apply the the filter `Name='Tom'` to a powerBI dataset (with two rows) to get the hang of how to use python with PowerBI.

The python script loads with:

```
# 'dataset' holds the input data for this script
```

How would I then do something like the following in PowerBI:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
    # is the following what starts off as 'dataset' ?
>>> df=pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Eric', 'Tom'], 'Age': [12, 14]})
>>> df.loc[df['Name'] == 'Tom']
   Name  Age
0  Tom   14
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems PowerBI does most of the heavy lifting, so you already have a pandas dataframe to start with called `dataset`. Here would be an example of doing the above:

```
# This line is not necessary, as PowerBI automatically imports pandas
# >>> import pandas as pd

# This line is also not necessary, as PowerBI automatically does this.
# Note, however that the dataframe is named `dataset` and not `df`.
# >>> df=pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Eric', 'Tom'], 'Age': [12, 14]})

# This is all you need to do
dataset = dataset.loc[dataset['Name'] == 'Tom']
```

This will produce one output dataset called `dataset`. If you want to store the original dataset and the new dataset, you can rename the output dataset, such as:

```
output = dataset...
```

Now you'll have two tables if you want to reference:

- dataset (original)
- output (with the filter applied)